# Webpack doesn't rendering html partials in another html partial

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-html-loader

I'm trying to import static html components in my templates,

I've this structure:

```
/src/home.html.ejs
/src/parts/header.html
/src/parts/breadcrumbs.html
```

/src/home.html.ejs body

```
<%= require('./header.html') %>
```

/src/parts/header.html

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<%= require('./breadcrumbs.html') %>
```

/src/parts/breadcrumbs.html

```
It's a breadcrumb!
```

When webpack is building I'm getting this in index.html:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<%= require('./breadcrumbs.html') %>
```

Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const miniCss = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        publicPath: '',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(s*)css$/,
                use: [
                    miniCss.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'fonts/'
                        }
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new miniCss({
            filename: 'style.css',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Home',
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/home.html.ejs'),
            filename: 'index.html',
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        port: 9000
    }
};
```

Also I found a couple of solutions when devs can use option interpolate in html-loader, but I'm using html-loader higher then v0.5.5 and this option was removed

What I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by using ejs-webpack-loader:

```
npm i ejs-webpack-loader
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const miniCss = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        publicPath: '',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
            test: /\.ejs$/,
            use: [
                {
                  loader: "ejs-webpack-loader",
                }
            ]
        },
            {
                test: /\.(s*)css$/,
                use: [
                    miniCss.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'fonts/'
                        }
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new miniCss({
            filename: 'style.css',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Home',
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/home.html'),
            filename: 'index.html',
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        port: 9000
    }
};
```

Structure

```
/src/home.html
/src/parts/header.ejs
/src/parts/breadcrumbs.ejs
```

in home.html

```
<%= require('./parts/header.ejs')() %>
```

in header.ejs

```
<%- require('./breadcrumbs.ejs')() %>
```

import child components with **<%-** not **<%=** and use brackets () in the end of import. You can pass some variables inside this brackets

in breadcrumbs.ejs

```
It's a breadcrumb!
```